# Upload large files properly using AWS lambda and S3 (with existing limits)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, aws-lambda, limit

Current limit of AWS Lambda on post/put size request is 6mb
Current limit of S3 on multipart upload is 5mb chunk size

5mb encoded file in upload request actually occupy more than 6mb, so the solution to upload  chunks straightforward to lambda functions doesn't work.

How properly implement large files uploading (more than 5mb)?

After some struggles I come across to solution to use Object Expiration rules as temp files for uploading sub chunks first then after sub chunk is uploaded I upload normal chunk with provided sub chunk id to fetch it from temp files and then concatenate in lambda function uploading chunk with sub chunk to make one part at least 5mb. This solution is working, but I still have to wait when sub chunk being uploaded, so fully parallel multipart uploading solution will not work this way (we still have to wait when sub chunks will uploaded).

Any better ideas how to solve such problem with limits of S3 and AWS Lambda?

Comment: Why not upload directly from client? This is possible for a private bucket.

Comment: @Ashan how? Request body size limited to 6mb but when you upload through http encoded 5mb file become 6mb+ so lambda just reject this request. Try yourself.

Comment: For large files its efficient to directly upload to S3 from client (Web Browser, Mobile Client & etc.) https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-signed-urls-fa0a0cf489db If this is the case you won't need to upload via a Lambda function.

Comment: @Ashan but we plan to use multiple storage solution not just only exclusively S3 and write dedicated code for 3S for each client (ios/android/web) too expensive and inefficient for us. I looking solution for Lamda and not direct upload.

Comment: Complementing @Ashan comment, you could use a per signed URL to upload from client: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html